# RConnection is causing page refresh issues using JSP

Tags: java, r, jsp

I have got a simple bit of code which connections a JSP page to R.

The code works fine but I have noticed that it only loads once! When I try to refresh the page it just hangs on loading.

The only way I can find around this is to restart the server every time which is not practical!

After some debugging I have found that the line of code causing the problem is as follows:

```
RConnection c = new RConnection();
```

I have tried setting `c` to `null` before creating a connection (I thought it might be hanging because a connection already existed) but that didn't change anything.

Does anyone know how to fix this rather weird issue?

Comment: Have you closed your connection at the end ??

Comment: Oops no I hadn't! That has fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: If you add it as an answer I will accept it. I have tried adding it myself but because I don't have 10 reputation I am unable to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try closing your connection at the end. It will solve your problem